# How to access custom headers on received reply message in my REST client?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I already know how to add a custom header to the reply message in my REST service:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Custom", "My message");
```

On the other hand, when I receive that message in the REST client how can I access that custom header?

I have implemented an `IClientMessageInspector` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842014/logging-soap-raw-response-received-by-a-clientbase-object/12845249#12845249).

But when doing:

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    if (!reply.IsFault)
    {
        int pos = reply.Headers.FindHeader("Custom", "ns");
    }
}
```

for some reason I am not able to access the "Custom" header but I can see the REST response and that is correct.

I'm not sure what to use on the ns parameter on the FindHeader call because I didn't use any on the Headers.Add call.

How can I correctly get the "Custom" header?

Comment: Did you try the headers property on the [WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.incomingresponse.aspx)?

Comment: I didn't know about the WebOperationContext! Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no other reply, I'm just writing this to close this question with Jeremy suggestion.

Use the `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse` header property.